# What is equivalent of android 'onUserLeaveHint' in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a flutter app and I am integrating PIP mode, I have implemented it but the problem is it only works when I click on a button, but I want to bring the app in Picture In Picture mode as user click on backbutton or my app goes in to background mode.
So for doing it I will have to add logic that switches my app into PiP mode instead of going into the background. For example, Google Maps switches to PiP mode if the user presses the home or recents button while the app is navigating. As per the android documentation we can catch this case by overriding onUserLeaveHint(), but I am not getting anything similar in flutter, I tried AppLifecycleState with the state paused but it is not working and the error occur " Activity must be resumed to enter picture-in-picture"

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for it?

Comment: There is nothing available in flutter equivalent of this, for achieving this we have to write our own flutter package that will contain the code in java or kotlin, and I did the same.

Comment: Is it possible to share your code?

Comment: Any update on sharing your code?